# Testing asynchronous code in Jest: done() not being called as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Here is a test suite written in Jest (v20.0.4).

The first 3 tests are expected behaviour, my question lies related to Test4.

```js
test('Test1: the list should contain 7', () => {
  const data = [1, 2, 7, 9];
  expect(data).toContain(7);
});
// > Passes as expected
```

```js
test('Test2: the list should contain 7', () => {
  const data = [1, 2, 7, 9];
  expect(data).toContain(8);
});
// > Fails as expected; Expected array: [1, 2, 7, 9] To contain value: 8
```

```js
test('Test3: the list should contain 7', (done) => {
  function callback(data) {
    expect(data).toContain(7);
    done();
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback([1, 2, 7, 9]);
  }, 500);
});
// > Passes as expected
```

```js
test('Test4: the list should contain 7', (done) => {
  function callback(data) {
    expect(data).toContain(8);
    done();
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback([1, 2, 7, 9]);
  }, 500);
});
// > Fails with Error "Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified"
```

Here is my question:

In Test4, `done()` is called immediately after the `expect` statement.
So, even if the expect statement does not pass, I guessed it should fail with error similar to Test2: `(Expected array: [1, 2, 7, 9] To contain value: 8)`

However, it fails with a timeout error as shown above which suggests that `done()` is never called.

Why? I don't get it!

Can someone please guide me through this behaviour?

I scanned through the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous) but could not find anything related to this.

Comment: I believe Jest returns as soon as it sees a failing expect statement. But any ideas regarding how to call done() immediately after failing expect, rather than waiting for Timeout to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `setTimeout` and Jest don't work as one might think. But there is a good way to deal with it:

- At the start of your test you can tell Jest to use fakeTimers:
  `jest.useFakeTimers();`
- When you need the callback to be executed you can trigger it with `jest.runAllTimers();`

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Timer mocks are definitely a great option. However, I think that using 'promise pattern' is better than 'callback pattern' which uses done()

Comment: Neither one is "better"--they serve two different purposes. Yes, the promise pattern is cleaner if you have code that uses promises, but sometimes you want to test callback-only functions that don't offer promises, in which case `done` is the only option (short of promisifying the callback by hand). In OP's code, the test throws before `done` is reached, but the solution is to catch the error and call `done` with it: `done(error)` to signal to Jest that the test failed. This avoids the nasty timeout.

Answer (score 7):

In your code, the `expect` call throws and `done` is never reached. As such, Jest waits until it times out and emits the nasty, unclear error you noticed.

The solution is to catch the throw and call `done(error)` to indicate to the Jest runner that the test failed.

```
test('Test4: the list should contain 7', done => {
  function callback(data) {
    try {
      expect(data).toContain(8);
      done();
    }
    catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback([1, 2, 7, 9]);
  }, 500);
});
```

A run of this gives the desired result:

```
Error: expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

Expected value: 8
Received array: [1, 2, 7, 9]
```

From the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#callbacks):

> If the `expect` statement fails, it throws an error and `done()` is not called. If we want to see in the test log why it failed, we have to wrap `expect` in a `try` block and pass the error in the `catch` block to `done`. Otherwise, we end up with an opaque timeout error that doesn't show what value was received by `expect(data)`.